# RoR JSON::ParserError 795: unexpected token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I need save `{"individual"=>"true", "multi-user"=>"true"}` to a string and then parse it to a JSON representation of the same hash. Unfortunately, this produces the following error:

```
JSON::ParserError in WizardsController#step 

795: unexpected token at '{"individual"=>"true", "multi-user"=>"true"}'
```

Comment: What is your question? If `'{"individual"=>"true", "multi-user"=>"true"}` is the content you are trying to parse, well, that's not JSON, so you cannot parse it as JSON. We probably can't you help here. Anyway, please read [ask] a proper question.

Comment: I need save {"individual"=>"true", "multi-user"=>"true"} to string and then parse it to the same hash

Comment: Does that you mean you want to *encode* that value as JSON? Encoding is different from parsing. Again, please [edit] your question and provide a proper description of what you are trying to do and your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use to_json on the hash, before you attempt to manipulate it:

```
{"individual"=>"true", "multi-user"=>"true"}.to_json
 => "{\"individual\":\"true\",\"multi-user\":\"true\"}"
```